# Is there a splitter for the Thunderbolt on my MacBook Air?

Tags: thunderbolt

My Macbook Air has only one Thunderbolt port, but I need to connect both to my internet cable and also to my VGA monitor. I have an adapter to do each, but obviously I can use only one at a time. What do I need to buy to be able to connect both the cable & the monitor?

Comment: To be useful, we'll need to know what model Air you purchased. Please check About This Mac on the device and tell us if it's a MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015) or some other model with the year and details intact. Also, we can't really guess if your cable modem uses USB or ethernet, so please explain or upload a picture and model of that as well.

Comment: I have a MacBook Air, that I purchased a couple of years ago. The "About" seems to just focus on the software version (which is OS X 10.9.5)

Comment: And the cable modem is a Motorola ??? that I purchased a couple of months ago, I believe this one: Motorola SBG6580 SURFboard DOCSIS 3.0 Wireless Cable Modem & Wi-Fi Router. It seems to drop a couple times an hour even though my laptop is right next to the cable modem, so I though a hard-wired connection might fix my problem. However, I still need to use my external monitor.

Comment: Yes there are, but not cheep, example : Belkin Thunderbolt 2 Express Dock HD
Thunderbolt Expansion Chassis, with Gigabit Ethernet, 3 x USB 3.0, 2 x Thunderbolt, HDMI, and 2 x Headphone - Mac/PC

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like a HengeDock: http://hengedocks.com/pages/vertical-macbook-air